# Automatic website creation using rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, templates, code-generation, scaffolding

I am looking for a template generator for rails, much like the scaffolding, but complete with preset pages and css, everything already built-in generically.

I am unsure where or how to search for this.

The reason I want something like that and not create one myself, is that I need to create a website really quickly with a certain preset theme

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem that you had, and could not find a solution. Therefore I built a gem for it.

```
https://github.com/bighostkim/simple-layout
```

It only applies to your development mode and it does not use asset to make it simple.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

[Rails Yard](http://www.railsyardcms.org/) may be the solution you are looking for. It is a CMS written in Rails.

[Rails CMS WIKI FORUM](https://github.com/jlapier/Rails-CMS-Wiki-Forum) 2nd option

[Rails Admin](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin) is great for data management (Create, Retrieve, Update, Delete).